# Trying to create Custom Query Editor

Tags: javascript, css, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am trying to create Custom query Editor here, which will rin SOQL Queried and give records in the form of `CSV file`. I know that i can use `Workbench` or `Data Loader` for this, but i need to do this programmatically.

While trying below code i am getting Error - 
`System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds: -1`

```
<apex:page controller="ExportCtrlr">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputTextarea id="theTextInput" value="{!sooql}" rows="5" cols="50"/><br/><br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Export Records" action="{!exportFun}" style="padding: 10px;"/> 
    </apex:form>

    <style type="text/css">
        form
        {
        margin:20px;
        }
    </style>
</apex:page>
```

And Apex Controller

```
public class ExportCtrlr 
{
 public String sooql {get;set;}

 public pageReference exportFun()
 {
  pageReference pg = new pageReference('/apex/ExportAsCSV?&soql='+sooql);
  pg.setRedirect(true);
  return pg;
 } 
}
```

`-------------------Updated Section ---------------------`

I have added ExportAsCSV Controller

```
public class ExportAsCSV 
{
    public String soql;

    public ExportAsCSV()
    {
        soql = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('soql');
    }
}
```

And ExportAsCSV VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="ExportAsCSV" cache="true" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#export.csv" language="en-US">

</apex:page>
```

Comment: The controller you pasted probably isn't where the error is occurring. This seems to be happening on the controller that controls the `ExportAsCSV` page. Can you update your question with that controller?

Comment: I've added ```ExportAsCSV ``` Controller and its VF page in the question. basically it is another page which is being used to download file in CSV format after clicking on Button.

Comment: Now the file is getting download in CSV format when i click on Command Button but the problem is that file is empty (downloaded file is not showing any record while i am adding query to the Input section)